# Api гугл карты стали платными?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api, frontend, google-maps

Api гугл карты стали платными?

Comment: Тынц альтернативы: https://m.habr.com/post/417715/

Comment: Сегодня попробовал https://leafletjs.com/ достаточно просто и удобно